# I'm trying desperately to add an image to my db (laravel 5.2)

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-5

I'm trying desperately to add an image to my db.it's all that remains to be done on my project

It fits well in my public folder, but in my db I have this:

> C: \ wamp \ tmp \ phpDDB4.tmp

and I can't find the problem.

**SlideController.php**

```php
public function validSlide(Request $request){
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
        'titre'=>'',
        'description'=>'',

    /*    Storage::put($destinationPath,File::get($image->getRealPath())),*/
    ]);
    $image = $request->file('photo');
    $input['photo'] = $image->getClientOriginalName();
    $destinationPath = public_path('/media');
    $image->move($destinationPath, $input['photo']);

    //Si l'une des contraintes n'est pas respectée on rédirige à nouveau vers la page du formulaire et on retourne les erreurs ainsi que l'ancien contenu des champs
    if($validator->fails()){
        return redirect('admin/add/slide')->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
    }
    //Sinon on fait l'insert
    $parameters = $request->except(['_token']);
    //$parameters = $request->all();
    //var_dump($parameters); die;
    //On appelle le modèle
    Slide::create($parameters);
    // On le rédirige vers la page d'accueil et on envoie un message flash de confirmation
    return redirect('admin/slide')->with(['success'=>'Slide enregistré !']);
}
```

**formulaire.blade.php**

```php
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="photo">Example file input</label>
    <input type="file" name="photo" class="form-control-file"
            id="photo" value="{{$slides->photo or ''}}">
 </div>
```

And my model:

**Slide.php**

```php
class Slide extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'slide';

    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = [
        'titre','description','photo'
    ];

    // the rest of the code

}
```

Thank you for your help. 
PS: sorry for my disastrous English ;-)

Comment: you changed the image name on move, but create use $request, so you also need to change image name in create

Comment: thank you for your answer but how should I do?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you declaring your variables inside an array

Comment: the variables for the image?

Comment: The code starting with `$image =` and ending with `$input['photo']),` should be moved outside the array being passed to the validator. I'm not sure it will fix what's going on but it would be a good place to start. Also, what does var_dump($parameters); die(); return?

Comment: no change nothing